# Authenticity Token in email body

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a Rails application and I have a button which lets the user send an email using mailto.

Here is the code:

```
<%= button_to('e-mail Us', href="mailto:<email address>?subject=Private Lessons", :class => 'btn btn-large btn-success') %>
```

It's working fine, but when the email opens, the body of the email has this in the body of the email.

```
authenticity_token=8wK4ulAWh4MedTQ7FwZw0YRyLCJtNpjnP040atdFnxA%3D
```

I definitely don't need it in the email. What can I do to have this not appear?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the mail_to helper method instead:

`<%= mail_to "test@test.com","email-Us", :subject => "Private Lessons" %>`

You can find more examples here: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-mail_to

Regards,

-Fernando